# Bootstrap section does not show up in Mobile browsers but shows up in Desktop version

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I'm trying to debug this issue in bootstrap but no luck so far, basically I have a section as below

```
<div class="content col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center animated fadeInLeft delayp1" style="opacity: 0; text-align: left">
            <h2 class="title" style="text-align: center">About Us</h2>
            <p>Testing</p>
```

Now when I open my site in my mobile browsers (safari or chrome), the About Us section does not show up but when I check in my laptop (safari or chrome), it shows up.

Any thoughts ? Pls share.

Thanks,
Deepesh

Comment: There is nothing here to suggest why your element is not showing. It's likely you have some CSS not shown here. Also, if you have `col-xs-12` there is no need to also have the `sm` and `md` variants.

Answer (score 0):

I made this for you.

```
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <h2 class="title" style="text-align: center">About Us</h2>
          <p>Testing</p>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Let me know.